# How to move the text cursor to a given position?

Tags: motion, point

How can I move the text cursor to any of these locations, using Lisp?

```lisp
(let ((beg (progn 
             (skip-syntax-backward "^ " (line-beginning-position))
             (point)))
      (end (progn 
             (skip-syntax-forward "^ " (line-end-position))
             (point))))
  ...)
```

I know we have `goto-char`, but `beg` and `end` here are not exactly character positions? ;)

I just want to move the cursor to `end`, for example.

Comment: `(goto-char (point-max))` to go the end. See the `Positions` chapter in the Emacs Lisp manual and its `Motion` subsection: `C-h i g(elisp)Positions`. Also search this site for `goto-char`: there are plenty of hits.

Comment: " ... beg and end here is not exactly character positions?" - yes, they *are* character positions.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info - the `elisp` tag is not meant as a tag for questions that have a snippet of Emacs Lisp code in them (otherwise, most questions on this site have something to do with Emacs Lisp and would contain the tag, which would make it useless for searching).

Comment: My first comment should say `(goto-char end)` to go to the `end` character position in your snippet. `(goto-char (point-max))` goes to the end of the buffer - apologies for my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

`(point)` specifically returns a character position, and therefore `beg` and `end` are both character positions.

Replacing `...` with `(goto-char end)` is precisely the answer.