# goto-char support for hexadecimal input

Tags: motion, eval-expression

I recently realized something weird regarding usability  of `goto-char` using GNU Emacs:

```
M-x goto-char
Go to char: 0x1000
Please enter a number (OP note: didn't work)
```

```
M-x goto-char
Go to char: (* 4 1024)
Please enter a number (OP note: didn't work)
```

I didn't have to use such a construct for the last 20 years of GNU Emacs usage, but I now need to deal with binary files using nhexl-mode and I can't find a good way to jump to specific addresses using hexadecimal (bonus: if it could be specified in a link such as org-mode link to a file:hex-address).

I can't imagine this very basic thing such as input a Lisp expression inside a value input is not possible.

Comment: "input a Lisp expression" --- In Elisp, 0x1000 is written "#x1000" instead of "0x1000"

Comment: And `goto-char #x1000` is working properly! Thanks!

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp)Integer Basics`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Shynur has already pointed out, both in a comment and in an answer, the syntax for a hexadecimal number which you can use directly in the `goto-char` interactive prompt. The following answer is concerned solely with the second part of the question: being able to use a Lisp expression in the interactive prompt.]

How a [command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html) gets its input is specified by using an [interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#index-evaluated-expression-argument) specification. E.g. `goto-char` has an "N" interactive spec[1]:

> n -- Number read using minibuffer.
>
> N -- Numeric prefix arg, or if none, do like code ‘n’.

That's probably general enough for 99.99% of the interactive uses of `goto-char` (e.g. and FWIW, I have never needed a calculator in order to get the position).

For use in Lisp programs, you can certainly pass whatever complicated expression you want as the argument to `goto-char`, as long as it returns some position. Here's an example from [a recent question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76460/how-to-move-the-text-cursor-to-a-given-position):

```
   ...
   (goto-char (progn 
                  (skip-syntax-forward "^ " (line-end-position))
                  (point)))
   ...
```

Finally, if you want to be able to have a calculator available, you can follow @Shynur's answer, or you can do something like this:

```el
(defun my/goto-char-with-calculator (res)
   (interactive "XType a Lisp expression that evaluates to a number: ")
   (goto-char res))
```

The doc string of `interactive` says:

> X -- Lisp expression read and evaluated.

So you can say e.g `M-x my/goto-char-with-calculator` and type an arbitrary Lisp expression that evaluates to a positive integer, e.g `(+ 1000 -992)` a.k.a `8` or more usefully `(+ (point) 10)` to advance 10 character positions past the current `point` in the buffer.

---

[1] `goto-char` is actually written in C and implemented in `editfns.c`, so I should have said: `goto-char` has the *equivalent* of an "N" interactive spec. It is actually implemented by specifying the function call that will do the argument handling: `(goto-char--read-natnum-interactive \"Go to char: \")`. But that's a detail...

Answer (score 5):

> I can't imagine this very basic thing such as input a Lisp expression inside a value input is not possible.

It is because there is no need to do that.  In Emacs, this behavior can be changed easily:

```lisp
(defun Robert-goto-char ()
  (interactive)
  (funcall #'goto-char (call-interactively 'eval-expression)))
```

You might put it in your `.emacs`.

---

Here are 2 examples:

```
M-x Robert-goto-char
Eval: #x1000
```

```
M-x Robert-goto-char
Eval: (* 4 1024)
```

---

Redefining `goto-char` is not recommended, because behaviors of some Elisp code may depend on this function.

Also see [2.4.15 Primitive Function Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Primitive-Function-Type.html):

> **we discourage redefinition of primitive functions**

Comment: Moreover, you can just use the correct hexadecimal syntax with `M-x goto-char` itself.